# Actualizar rama antigua

Tags: git, bitbucket

tengo un problema y es que tengo una rama muy antigua que quiero actualizar pero va 239 commits por detrás, habría alguna manera de actualizar la rama de una manera rápida y sencilla, actualmente la rama no ha sido tocada todo lo que hay en la rama esta en master lo que quiero es traerme master a mi rapa sin tener conflictos para poder actualizarla con todos los commits.

Un saludo y gracias.

Answer (score 6):

**Para actualizar tu rama xxx con la rama master**, te situas en la rama xxx:

```
git merge master
```

Los conflictos no se pueden elegir a voluntad, si lo hay y *Git* no puede resolverlos, tendrás que arreglarlos manualmente. Puedes crear una nueva rama a partir de xxx antes del merge para preservar ese código intacto.

> Editado

Al hacer un merge de otra rama *mezclas* el contenido de tu rama local actual con el de la rama que *mergeas*, seguidamente se resuelven los posibles conflictos y finalmente puedes actualizar el contenido de la rama en remoto con:

```
git pull
```

o

```
git pull -f
```

*Nota: este último comando **fuerza** la actualización en caso de que el remoto rechace la misma.*

Comment: una vez hecho el merge no hay que hacer un commit y push? para que el branch remoto quede actualizado

Comment: si puedes hacer el commit y push, pero tiene la razon debes verificar que no tengas conflictos para proceder con lo anterior.

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero es actualizar la rama, llamémosle  ***old***.

Nos aseguramos que tenemos todos los cambios de master:

```
git checkout master

git pull
```

Cambiamos a la rama old:

```
git checkout old
```

El resultado debería ser algo como:

> Branch 'old' set up to track remote branch 'old' from 'origin'.
>
> Switched to a new branch 'old'

Nos aseguramos que tengamos la última versión de *old*:

```
git pull
```

Fusionamos la rama *old* con los cambios actuales de master que tenemos en local:

```
git merge master
```

Ojo que hasta este punto seguimos en la rama *old*. Puedes verificarlo con:

```
git status
```

Finalmente hacemos push del branch al repositorio remoto que tengas configurado:

```
git push origin old
```

(Esto subirá el branch y lo creará si no existiese)

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Primero verificas la rama donde te encuentras:

```
git branch
```

Te cambias a la rama que deseas:

```
git branch <nombre_rama>
```

Verificas el estado de esa rama:

```
 git status
```

Si hay cambios debes hacer el commit respectivo, sino haces el merge con la rama master local (todo esta de forma local)

```
git merge master
```

Para subirlos a tu repositorio remoto:

```
git push origin master
```

Answer (score -1):

Apuntar a master y traer lo último desde el origen

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

Apuntar a tu rama y mezclar lo que hay en la rama local de master

```
git checkout tu-rama
git merge master
```

Comment: Es recomendable que agregues algún texto descriptivo a tu respuesta.

Comment: Esta respuesta es poco útil si no sabes como funcionan los comandos que indicas. Añade un texto explicativo que indique lo que hacen.

Comment: pidió una manera rápida y sencilla, creo que todos tenemos acceso a la documentación para ver lo que significan los comandos